# Different sizes for individual vertices in BufferGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

For my current task, I am making a 2D scatterplot with three.js, and need to make the points different sizes. [Here](https://shaiyon.com/DataShapes/2d) is my current implementation. I can't figure out how to make the sizes of the points different and derived from the "radius" feature. Additionally, I want to make a small black border around every point that is the same thickness regardless of size, like [this](https://www.pngkit.com/png/detail/26-263930_circle-svg-png-icon-free-download-black-circle.png). For these types of features, I've seen that vertexShaders are traditionally used, but I want to render an almost static image and nothing needs to change during runtime. Here is relevant code:

```
    var coordinates = new Float32Array(data_points.length*3);
    var colors = new Float32Array(data_points.length*3);
    var sizes = new Float32Array(data_points.length);

    for (var i=0; i<data_points.length; i++) {
        // Set vector coordinates from data
        let vertex = new THREE.Vector3(data_points[i].x, data_points[i].y, 0);
        let color = new THREE.Color(color_array[data_points[i].label]);
        vertex.toArray(coordinates, i*3);
        color.toArray(colors, i*3);
        sizes[i] = data_points[i].radius*100;
    }

    let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
    geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(coordinates, 3));
    geometry.setAttribute('color', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
    geometry.setAttribute('size', new THREE.BufferAttribute(sizes, 1 ));

    let pointsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
        size: 100,
        sizeAttenuation: true,
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://fastforwardlabs.github.io/visualization_assets/circle-sprite.png"),
        transparent: true
    });

    let points = new THREE.Points(geometry, pointsMaterial);
```

This is a relatively easy problem, but I'm not experienced with javascript and could use any help I can get. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `Points`, you are most likely looking at needing to make a custom shader (vertex+fragment).

But, as a thought, is your data so large that you couldn't use meshes instead? A combination of scaled [`CircleBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CircleBufferGeometry) as a `Mesh` and a `Line` (or [fat lines](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=line#webgl_lines_fat)) could do exactly what you want.

```js
let W = window.innerWidth;
let H = window.innerHeight;
let aspect = W / H;
const frustumSize = 100;

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true,
  alpha: true
});
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(frustumSize * aspect / -2, frustumSize * aspect / 2, frustumSize / 2, frustumSize / -2, 1, 100);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
scene.add(camera);

// circle
const geo = new THREE.CircleBufferGeometry(10, 32);
const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0xaaff55
});
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);

// outline
const geo2 = geo.clone();
// strip the center point from CircleBufferGeometry:
geo2.attributes.position.array = geo.attributes.position.array.slice(3);
geo2.attributes.position.count--;
geo2.attributes.normal.array = geo.attributes.position.array.slice(3);
geo2.attributes.normal.count--;
geo2.deleteAttribute("uv"); // lines don't need UVs
geo2.index = null; // don't need indexing for this kind of line
const mat2 = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x55aa00
});
const line = new THREE.LineLoop(geo2, mat2);

// data point
const group = new THREE.Group();
group.add(mesh);
group.add(line);
scene.add(group);

group.userData.scalingMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeScale(2, 2, 2); // for storing the scaling matrix

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function resize() {
  W = window.innerWidth;
  H = window.innerHeight;
  aspect = W / H;
  renderer.setSize(W, H);
  camera.left = frustumSize * aspect / -2;
  camera.right = frustumSize * aspect / 2;
  camera.top = frustumSize / 2;
  camera.bottom = frustumSize / -2;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  render();
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);

resize();
render();

// pretend this is reacting to your mouseovers
let over = true;
const resetMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4()
setInterval(() => {
  group.applyMatrix4((over) ? group.userData.scalingMatrix : resetMatrix.getInverse(group.userData.scalingMatrix));
  over = !over;
  render();
}, 2000);
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

There is also (and this is outside my sphere of knowledge) the [`SVGRenderer`](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/renderers/SVGRenderer), which can render shapes as SVG objects. This may be easier to work with, again depending on your data. See a demo here: https://threejs.org/examples/#svg_sandbox

Comment: Thank you so much! Using meshes worked perfectly, now I just have to fix the raycasting and my project is done. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @ShaiyonHariri If this answer resolved your question, please mark it as accepted. I also had a problem with the raycaster, which is why I didn't include it in my example. We'll be here should you decide to ask a (new) question about it. :)

Comment: Thank you Jim! I will be asking a new question soon, I have made a lot of progress on my original visualization (at the same link) but the raycaster is complete mayhem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `PointsMaterial` to achieve the intended affect. You need a custom shader material for this or you try to enhance `PointsMaterial` with [Material.onBeforeCompile()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/Material.onBeforeCompile). I suggest you study the implementation of the following official example to check out the former approach:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_custom_attributes_points

An important part of the code is the vertex shader, which enables points of different sizes:

```js
attribute float size;
attribute vec3 customColor;

varying vec3 vColor;

void main() {

    vColor = customColor;

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

    gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

}
```

Notice the additional `size` attribute.